# Adjacent sibling selector, select `former_element` in `former_element + target_element`

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
h3 + ul { margin-top: 0; }
```

This targets `ul`, is it possible to target `h3` instead?

Instead of selecting all `ul`s that appear after a `h3`, I want to select all `h3`s that precede a `ul`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no selector that does what you're looking for*.

---

The ["Selectors Level 4" specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/) is currently in draft phase and is not implemented by any browser that I know of at the time of writing. It introduces the concept of a selector ["subject"](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject), which would allow you to specify the part of the selector that the styles are applied to:

```
/* applies to ul */
h3 + ul {
    margin-top: 0;
}

/* applies to h3 */
!h3 + ul {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

---

<sub>* yet</sub>

Comment: But, but, this is so obviously basic that it should simply exist!

Comment: @Elmo, well if it's so obvious and basic, feel free to go make it. The web is an open platform after all.

Comment: @zzzzBox An open platform that lets you use new features after decades.  -_-